# No resource identifier found for attribute 'apikey' in package 'android'

Tags: android

```
<?xml version ="1.0" encoding ="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <com.google.android.maps.Mapview
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:id="@+id/themap"
        android:apikey = "AIzaSyDc9ac67bCYPqhVYz9pxhTJsK9shZH3iQg"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

it is my activity_main.xml file ...bt it shows the error mentioned above...i have also included android:name="com.google.android.maps" in my manifest file..plz help

Comment: the error is self explanatory. take a look at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2

Comment: Include the jar file or run the application with the google api

Comment: i followed that link bt it wasnt helpful for me....i am new on android and follwing tuturials and doing the same ....plz treat me as a beginner..thankx

Comment: i am running the application with virtual device targeted to google api (19) and i am unable to find its jar file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether in your project properties you have selected it as `Google APIs`

[image]

follow this if you still facing [problem](http://mobiforge.com/design-development/developing-with-google-maps-v2-android)

Comment: i have seletcted google apis but it isnt showing google play services like it is shown in photo...

Comment: check this link http://mobiforge.com/design-development/developing-with-google-maps-v2-android